# Rails save record second time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have function :

```
def vote
    Story.increment_counter(:vote, params[:id])
end
```

First i look to database and i see : vote = 2.
When i refresh the page i look to database again see : vote = 4.

Second try :

```
def vote
    story = Story.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @test = story.vote
    @test2 = @test.to_i + 1
    story.vote = @test2.to_i
    story.save
end
```

In viem i have result : @test = 2, @test2 = 3, but in database vote = 4.

When i use +5 i have in database +10 votes.

I use ruby 4.

Thanks for yours help.

Comment: From where and when does `vote` get called?

Comment: Can you please post some more information, so the question is more clear?  Please post the `Story#increment_counter` method?  Also, it does not look like `@test` and `@test2` need to be instance variables and I don't think you need to call `to_i` because they are already integers.